# Вопрос по JS. Убрать класс выделенного div

Tags: javascript

Не могу разобраться, как сделать .removeClass
   на выделенный объект.
   То есть, чтобы выделенному div не назначался класс .highlighted

```
<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="XxOXRo" data-default-tab="css,result" data-user="askin" data-pen-title="XxOXRo" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/askin/pen/XxOXRo/">XxOXRo</a> by alees (<a href="https://codepen.io/askin">@askin</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
```

```
https://codepen.io/askin/pen/XxOXRo
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBdbwa

Comment: Как-то еще хуже стало. Прозрачность все равно не ушла, что задана в стиле .highlighted, то есть стиль не remove-ится, да еще и добавилось выделение div, то есть, на который навел на первый, потом по другим перехожу, а он все равно активен остается

Comment: Вы сами все запутали в этом плане ;) хотели чтобы highlighted не добавлялся на ховере – не добавляется. А там уж с прозрачностью смотрите на разметку, он у вас в контейнер выше добавляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {

        $(".div1").mouseenter(function () {
            $(".div1").addClass("highlighted");
          $(this).removeClass("highlighted");
        });

        $(".wrapper").mouseleave(function () {               
            $(".div1").removeClass("highlighted");
        });
```

});

Comment: Спасибо! Именно, то, что и требовалось!

Answer (score 0):

Не понял, что ты точно хочешь. 
Но попробуй использовать на каждый div `each(function)`
То есть

```
$('.div1').each(fucntion(){
  $(this).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('className')
  })
})
```